# is there any diffrence between fn:lower-case and lower_case function in sql server

Tags: sql-server

in x query of sql-server, there is a function which can be called in two ways.

ex:

```
 DECLARE @x xml = N'abcDEF!@4';  
    SELECT @x.value('fn:lower-case(/text()[1])', 'nvarchar(10)');

    DECLARE @x xml = N'abcDEF!@4';  
    SELECT @x.value('lower-case(/text()[1])', 'nvarchar(10)');
```

q1) So please tel me  which one should be used and when?

yours sincerely

Comment: Have you tried "Googling"? I suggest you try this: https://www.google.com.au/#q=sql+server+fn:lower-case+vs+lower-case

Comment: Question is copied from here https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1885462/is-there-any-diffrence-between-fnlowercase-and-lowercase-function-in-sql-server

Comment: It's bad etiquette to multi-post the same question to different forums at the same time as that causes a lot of redundant work for all parties involved. If you don't get a satisfactory answer after a reasonable time, at least include a link to your original question when posting to a different site.

Comment: @Prdp - the question was answered there as well "use neither, use the LOWER function instead"